# How can I stop random sampling in random-forest using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, random-forest

I use the function `CvRTrees::train`. This function samples the data automatically. The problem is that I have already sampled the data before passing it. I don't want it to re-sample again. Is there is any flags to be passed to stop this sampling or I have to remove this line from the code?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution
go to the file mlrtrees.cpp, line 374, it will be something like this

`int idx = cvRandInt( &rng ) % nsamples;`

change it to be

`int idx = i;`

btw, it is not tested yet